Estimating global sea level at lower temperatures
In particular I'm interested in finding out what the sea level would be under a sustained average of -1.5°C below the pre-industrial mean, i.e an average global temperature of 12.23°C. However a resource that lets one estimate world sea-level, and ice cover, under different temperature regimes would be very useful. The point I'm interested in, in particular, appears to be a point that paleo-temperature fluctuations blow through relatively rapidly. This would make a direct reading of the temperature and sea-level record curves useless in this case because both the temperature and sea-level are both in flux. If I can get a rough number I can use the Flood Map to look at the shorelines I'm interested in but first I need to work out roughly how low the sea level would be pushed by such a small, but sustained, change in temperature.
